# User Object and Membership Object Report for Community Users

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, sales-cloud, joined-reports, community-cloud

Looking to build a report in Salesforce where I have data that can link the two objects but can not figure out how to pull the data.

Needing a Report with the User Email and Membership Number tied to the community user that has migrated to our new SSO.

On the "User Object" lives:

- ContactID,
- Migration checkbox, and
- Email

On "Membership Object" lives

- Contact ID,
- Community User, and
- Membership Number

I can run a join report that pulls everything I need, but I don't know how to filter one based on the other and merge the results. I also have not figured out how to do a Custom Report Type because it wants to tie the "User" to the "Modified by" or "Created by" field, not the "Contact".

Everything is there to do what I need to do... I'm just not connecting it in a report since this team is needing to access this report regularly.

Please send help...

Comment: `but I don't know how to filter one based on the other and merge the results.` - please elaborate using [edit]

Answer (score 0):

We ended up creating a custom object to connect all our dots.